# RecyclerView: Change itemTextColor in adapter onClickListener and show in onCreate when app is launched again

Tags: java, arrays, xml, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I am creating an android app that is having both news and ads in a RecyclerView.I tried to use SharedPreferences. But i want text color to change once an item is clicked and it'll remain in it's new color forever even when app is relaunched

**Please your assistance will be of great help to me thank you**

[Before an item is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6b55.png)

[After clicking an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikiea.png)

Comment: Voting to close as you have not provided any details to actually get help. You tried SharedPreferences? How? What have you done to solve your own problem and where _specifically_ are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to use SharedPreferences then use it and then feedback. I guess shared preferences should work in your use case if you don't wanna save complex data structure(in that case you can use SQLite I guess).

If your news/add item has an id you can save "id" as key and "true/false or visited date info as complex text" as value (key-value pair) in your shared preferences so in the next launch, you should just check in your shared preferences first. But for a large number of items, I am not sure it is a great idea or not, in that case, you can preload or runtime load user-specific info while loading recycler view and apply your user-specific customizatrion.

Comment: Thanks bruh, i have solved it successfully using interface and SQlite Database. Where isRead is boolean which becomes true or false

Comment: In the long run you may have to save the database in the server that maps user id to news id and corresponding info. So while loading a chunk of news in the recycler view, you have to query in the database for that chunk info whether the user has already read it or not(or other info) and show it in the front end. local database is suitable for optimal size but for a large number of news, you shouldn't save it in the local database rather while loading a chunk of news you can prefetch data from the server and save it to the local SQLite/shared preferences temporarily for usage and clear later.